# Excel Link two cells in different sheets using when changed macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets. I have a cell in WORKSHEET A with range name TRACK1 and a cell in WORKSHEET B with range name TRACK2.

Each TRACK1 and TRACK2 are validated from a list. The user can change either cell from the drop-down list shown when the cell is selected.

I want to be able to allow the user to change either and have the other be also changed to match. Change value of TRACK1 and TRACK2 is changed, and vice versa.

I know how to do this basic macro, but how to stop the event propagating?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("TRACK1")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("TRACK2") = Range("TRACK1")
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("TRACK2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("TRACK1") = Range("TRACK2")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In worksheet A's code module, use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("TRACK1")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("WORKSHEET B").Range("TRACK2") = Range("TRACK1")
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In worksheet B's code module, use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("TRACK2")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("WORKSHEET A").Range("TRACK1") = Range("TRACK2")
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @YowE3K why would I be getting `Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed` pointing to `Range("TRACK1") = Range("TRACK2")`

Comment: I used the naming box top left, below the toolbar to name the cells. I can access each cell value in any workbook by doing `=TRACK1`. These are global scope for the workbook right? I also tried speicifying worksheet like this `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("TRACK1") = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("TRACK2")` but fails with `subscript out of range` error.

Comment: It appears we need to qualify the range reference that isn't in the active sheet - let me make a change.

Comment: @TheRealPapa OK - have a look at the update I just made.  Make sure you change the worksheet names to the actual names.  Oops - just noticed your comment.  You say you tried that?  Are you sure you used the right sheet name for the right range name?